# How to interpret the solution and how to work with it further?

Tags: equation-solving, pure-function

Please help me understand the solution to the following problem:

```
L[x] = ArcTan[x] x;
MM[x] = L[x] Sqrt[1 - x^2];
MM1[x] = Simplify[D[MM[x], x]];
Solve[MM1[x] == 0 && Re[x] > 0, x, Reals]
```

The answer is given as:

```
{{x -> Root[{-#1 + #1^3 + ArcTan[#1] (-1 + #1^2 + 2 #1^4) &, 
     0.79562547510070363232}]}}
```

How to work with it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [Root documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html)

Comment: Your function definitions only work for the literal input of `x`. Definitions generally should have a pattern on the LHS, e.g., `L[x_] = ArcTan[x] x;` In the `Solve`, since the domain is restricted to `Reals`, you could use the simpler `x > 0` rather than `Re[x] > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```mathematica
L[x] = ArcTan[x] x;
MM[x] = L[x] Sqrt[1 - x^2];
MM1[x] = Simplify[D[MM[x], x]];
sol = Solve[MM1[x] == 0 && Re[x] > 0, x, Reals]

(* {{x -> 
   Root[{-# + #^3 + ArcTan[#] (-1 + #^2 + 2 #^4)& , 
     0.79562547510070363231522425127937442335`20.296114767186726}]}} *)
```

```mathematica
N[x /. sol[[1]]]

(* 0.795625 *)
```

---

See the examples of [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for other ways to work with the obtained solutions.

Comment: Hello. What is the first part of the answer?


`-# + #^3 + ArcTan[#] (-1 + #^2 + 2 #^4)&`


Can this part be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
L[x] = ArcTan[x] x;
MM[x] = L[x] Sqrt[1 - x^2];
MM1[x] = Simplify[D[MM[x], x]];
res = x /. Solve[MM1[x] == 0 && Re[x] > 0, x, Reals][[1]]
```

"res" is now an exact number like 2 or Pi, the exact root of some polynomial. You can calculate with it and as long as you are using exact numbers, the result is always exact. E.g.:

```
Exp[2 res]
```

[image]

However as soon as you introduce a machine number (not exact), the result will become a machine number. E.g:

```
1. Exp[2 res]

4.90989
```

You may force the conversion to machine numbers also with the "N" operator.